# mysqli query. Is there any way to display error? even though my query works fine

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to display some data from the database into an html table. My other query works fine, i was able to retrieve some of the other tables and displaying it to my website although this particular query does not even though if have a function mysqli_error(). I tried executing the query directly from my database (phpmyadmin) and it retrieve it just fine.

here are my codes.

Note: $p_id variable has some data which is '3'.

PHP

```
$p_sql = "SELECT p.package_name, p.package_price, p.package_details, p.package_categories, p.package_id FROM event_table as e inner join package as p on e.package_id = p.package_id where e.package_id = '$p_id' group by e.package_id";
$data_p = mysqli_query($conn, $p_sql) ;
$result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data_p);

$p_amount = $result['package_price'];



  while ($record_p = mysqli_fetch_array($data_p)) {


echo "<table border = 1>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>" . "Package Name" . "</th>";
echo "<th>" . "Package Price" . "</th>";
echo "<th>" . "Package Details" . "</th>";
echo "<th>" . "Package Categories" . "</th>";

echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>"; 
echo "<td>" . "<br />" .  $record_p['package_name'] . "<br />" . "</td>" ;
echo "<td>" . "<br />" .  $record_p['package_price'] . "<br />" . "</td>" ;
echo "<td>" . "<br />" .  $record_p['package_details'] . "<br />" . "</td>" ;
echo "<td>" . "<br />" .  $record_p['package_categories'] . "<br />" . "</td>" ;

echo "<tr/>";





}
echo "</table>";

if(!$data_p){
        echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($conn));
    }
```

Comment: It might be the case where there are no rows returned. What is `mysqli_num_rows($data_p)`? Just because there were no rows, doesn't mean that there was an error.

Comment: Why are you using mysqli_fetch_assoc() before the mysqli_fetch_array() ?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com/ gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli.

Comment: what is the column type of `e.package_id`? int, or varchar? If it's int then your query will never match any rows because `3` does not equal `'3'`. The single quotes round the variable are telling the database to interpret your variable as a string containing the character "3" rather than the actual number 3. Not the same thing. P.S. This would never have been an issue if you'd used proper parameterisation in the first place as I suggested above, because the DB library will take care of that kind of thing for you, you just tell it the type of the variable and it does the rest.